# How can i send emails from azure sql when a certain condition is met

Tags: azure-sql-database, sendgrid, email

I have an azure sql database where i store some user information about scheduled tasks. I need to allow user to get a notification 30mins before the event starts, i cannot do this in the application it self as the application is a windows form app. I checked some solutions where they use logic apps but it only allows to send when a new record is added or updated.

But i need to check for the current time and the start time of the schedule and send the email if there is a difference less than 30 mins

My database is as follows

```
Name = John doe
Email = johndoe@gmail.com 
Startdate = 09/12/2019 12:45 AM
Enddate = 09/12/2019 1:45 AM
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: You can have a small Winforms app or Console Application with same DB Connection to send mail alone, which will periodically check `StartTime` and `CurrentTime`. You can host this App in **Task Scheduler** , so the application runs if the condition satisfy else would terminate.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion first You have to create a table (with identity as primary key and let's named EmailDetails) that contains all the email fields. Then create an Logic App that triggers on an insert into that table. You can then connect the SendGrid module to send emails as shown in [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1226872/Send-Email-from-Azure-SQL-using-Logic-App) article.

Run a stored procedure every 1 hour using Azure Automation (as shown [here](https://www.rdx.com/blog/azure-automation-scheduling-stored-procedures)) that insert a new record on the EmailDetails table when a scheduled task is going to start.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Automation is the best option here, but you could simply include the logic within the Automation Runbook to check for the current time and the scheduled start time and trigger the email from there.

The downside is that a single schedule can only run once every hour. The most frequent interval a schedule in Azure Automation can be configured for is one hour. If you require schedules to execute more frequently than that, there are two options:

1. Create a [webhook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-webhooks) for the runbook and use [Azure Scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-get-started-portal) to call the
   webhook. Azure Scheduler provides more fine-grained granularity when
   defining a schedule.
2. Create four schedules all starting within 15 minutes of each other
   running once every hour. This scenario allows the runbook to run
   every 15 minutes with the different schedules.